# Extra tables are added when I create a new Database

Tags: sql-server

This is a really weird problem. When I create a new DB from a script I'm getting extra tables added. These aren't system type tables but regular tables that look like they may have come from a past project. There are 3 of them, each with 2 columns, either ints or nchar(10) with no keys, constraints, triggers, or indices.

I have no idea where this is coming from or how I can fix it. Right now I just delete the tables but it's a bit annoying and I'd like to fix the issue.

Here is a script I wrote that reproduces the error:

```
CREATE DATABASE X;
GO

USE X;
GO

CREATE TABLE Y(
  YId INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT pk_yid PRIMARY KEY(YId));
GO

CREATE TABLE Z(
  ZId INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT pk_zid PRIMARY KEY(ZId));
GO
```

After I run this script my DB is created, but it has 5 tables instead of 2.

Running `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` just lists my extra tables as BASE TABLE, exactly the same as the ones I defined (all other columns are the same as well).

This is happening on SQL Server 2008 R2 
(Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.50.2500.0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone added tables to the [model database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186388.aspx).

> When a CREATE DATABASE statement is issued, the first part of the
>   database is created by copying in the contents of the model database.
>   The rest of the new database is then filled with empty pages.
>
> If you modify the model database, all databases created afterward will
>   inherit those changes. For example, you could set permissions or
>   database options, or add objects such as tables, functions, or stored
>   procedures.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the case. I removed the tables from the model database.

Answer (score 7):

New databases are copies of the model database. If they're in model, they'll be in every new database you create.